# Why does ED-209 have that numerical designation?

Tags: robocop, robocop-1987, robocop-2014

I was looking at the [wikipedia page for ED-209](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ED-209) and I couldn't find why in or out of universe, the number 209 was picked.

I also don't remember anything from the movie explaining it. Is it just the 209th attempt?

Is it ever explained in any movie (reboot or otherwise)?

Comment: The foundations of Omnicorp Tower include a sizeable mass grave containing what's left of the test subjects of ED-1 through ED-208.

Comment: I've no idea why someone would downvote this perfectly good question...

Comment: @Valorum I find that people downvote questions they don't like, find uninteresting, or find personally offensive for some reason [1], instead of using the downvote to signify "this question is poorly phrased, based on utterly wrong assumptions, or shows a total lack of research effort". ([1] in the interest of honesty, I downvote most manwha/manga/FL/ML/isekai/"what's the first [thing]?" questions on sight. Am I using the downvote button as intended? No, but it's therapeutic).

Comment: 209 could be derived from 108, which is a *very* significant number in Hinduism & related traditions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/108_(number)#Religion_and_the_arts

Comment: @AndresF. *I downvote most manwha/manga/FL/ML/isekai* is inappropriate voting, IMHO.  I don't like them either, but I've played around with the "ignore/hide" tag settings as well as harcoding "not X!" in the search bar and just well, ignore them.  There are popular subjects that annoy me far more (hint: 2 of them figure in the top 8 tags) and I also ignore them.  Downvoting a Q because you don't like a particular genre is just petty.  Plus, I'd get carpal tunnel from it.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica oh, I know it's "inappropriate" (sort of, there's no hard guideline really, just uses and customs), but I still do it: it's therapeutic for me. Also, most questions are missing tags initially, _so I cannot hide them_ (this is typical of manga/isekai, which is seldom tagged so initially). I usually hide tags (I have plenty ignored tags already) but those questions that slip through get the downvote hammer. This means my bias is against _newer, untagged questions_. Is it bad? I dunno, but who cares: it satisfies _me_! I only have one vote anyway, it won't make a dent.

Answer (score 11):

ED-209 appears to be the latest of Omnicorp's Enforcement Droid programme, suggesting that earlier models had a lower number. It's not immediately clear whether this is the *209th* iteration or something more akin to the way that [software versions are numbered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) (e.g. v2.09) but in the [reboot film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCop_(2014_film)) an earlier and smaller model is EM-20*8*, with ED-20*9* described as its '*big brother*'.

> Like big brother ED-209, EM-208 offers the full media suite: 360 infrasonic cameras, audio targeting, and real-time backup. Vocal mediation cued in over 1,500 languages with 500+ regional dialects remotely updatable.
>
> <sub><sup>[Omnicorp Viral Website: EM-208](https://web.archive.org/web/20130720005609/http://www.omnicorp.com/products/em-208.php)</sup></sub>

---

In the animated TV series, a later model of Enforcement Droid was the [ED-*260*](https://robocop.fandom.com/wiki/ED-260), suggesting that the numbering is sequential (or at the very least ascending).

Whereas in the 1990 Marvel '*Robocop*' comic, Dick Johnson orders the creation of the ED-**3**09 (war model) after the failure of the 209 series, suggesting that the numbering is semantic like software.

[image]
**<sub><sup>[Robocop #6 (2010)](https://robocop.fandom.com/wiki/RoboCop_6_(2010_comic_series))</sup></sub>**

Comment: I want one now!!! http://www.theoldrobots.com/images58/robo11.JPG / http://www.theoldrobots.com/images58/robo9.JPG

Comment: #TIL "infrasonic" is actually a thing, not just scifi technobabble. Who knew?

Comment: @FreeMan Although they lose points immediately by calling them 'cameras' when 'infrasonic' would be below-human-range-of-hearing *noise*, not a part of the emissions spectrum, and you'd use a microphone rather than a camera to pick it up.. And also there's pretty much zero use for equipment like that in surveillance.

Comment: @FreeMan Whales, tiger roars, and some old lifts are all infrasonic, I'm not sure how you make an infrasonic camera

Comment: @Shadur Perhaps an infrasonic *sonar*, but I'm at a loss as to how or why that would work better than a classic ultrasonic sensor.